# @Helpers In ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to use `Razor helper` in .net core

I use this code

```
@{
   void DrawRow(CategoryModel child, int parentNo)
    {
     @<text>
       <tr  style="display: none;">
        <td><span class="treegrid-indent"></span><span class="treegrid-expander"></span>@child.Name</td>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </text>;
     }
 }
```

but when use this , get error

> The "@" character must be followed by a ":", "(", or a C# identifier.  If you intended to switch to markup, use an HTML start tag,

Comment: this might help: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/344/what-happened-to-helpers-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve same requirement using a [view component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#walkthrough-creating-a-simple-view-component) in ASP.NET Core application, like below.

*ViewComponent class*

```
[ViewComponent(Name = "DrawRow")]
public class DrawRowComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(DrawRowModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

*ViewComponent Razor view*

```
@model DrawRowModel

@*display: none;*@

<tr style="">
    <td>
        <span class="treegrid-indent"></span>
        <span class="treegrid-expander"></span>
        @Model.child.Name
    </td>
</tr>
```

*Model Class(es)*

```
public class CategoryModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DrawRowModel
{
    public CategoryModel child { get; set; }
    public int parentNo { get; set; }
}
```

*Invoke view component in `Test` View page*

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test";


    var model = new DrawRowModel { child = new CategoryModel { Name = "Category" }, parentNo = 0 };
}

<h1>Test</h1>


@for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
    model.child.Name = "Category" + i.ToString();
    model.parentNo = i;
    <table>
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("DrawRow", model)
    </table>
}
```

*Test Result*

[image]